# MYSQL query last time column had a different value based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a MYSQL table with the following data. I need a query to find out the last time a column had another value other than the current value. The possible values are red, yellow or green. For example I would like to find out what time overall had another colour in it's column other than yellow which it is currently assuming the time now is 11:48. If we look at the rows, the timestamp where it was another colour other than yellow was 2015-01-26 11:45:39 when it was green. But what is a query to do this?

```
timeStamp |
overall |
siteAvailability |
traffic |
orders |
data |
customer |

2015-01-26 11:45:39 |
green |
green |
green |
green |
green |
yellow |

2015-01-26 11:48:14 |
yellow |
green |
green |
green |
green |
yellow |

2015-01-26 11:48:14 |
yellow |
green |
green |
green |
green |
yellow |

2015-01-26 11:48:39 |
yellow |
green |
green |
green |
green |
yellow |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you say siteAvailability but your example seems to be consistent with overall.  Assuming you meant the later how about:

```
select max(timestamp) from file
                           where overall !=(
select overall from file
                    where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from file))
```

Comment: Yes you are right I meant overall in the question. I have updated it. Thanks for spotting this.